# JDeveloper reference project inside application

Tags: reference, project, jdeveloper

I never used JDeveloper so please bear with me. So far I have 2 Java projects inside my Application.

Project #A: Has proxy web services references, it compiles without errors.
Project #B: Is supposed to call the web service project.

I am unable to reference Project #A from Project #B. Both projects reside inside the same application.

Classes from Project #A are not "recognized" in Project #B.

I have a class called "Claimant" in Project#A. I cannot use that object type inside Project #B.

I have tried the "import" statement but to no avail. import statement in Project #A doesn't recognize Project #B

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Go into the projectB project properties and under dependencies set it so it depends on ProjectA

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem like you just had. Like mentioned the correct way to fix this is with right clicking the project -> going under Project properties ->dependencies and check the dependency.

But this is just part of the problem. The other part which was wrong with my setup was regarding Jdeveloper, Java versions etc.

After fiddling with the setup, un-installing all different Java versions, clearing everything from Jdeveloper (Also in the Roaming folder), and re-installing everything from a start step by step. Only after that I was able to fix the problem for whatever reason.

A bit of data on my setup:

-JDeveloper 12.1.3

-2.1 MAF Extension

-Java 8

P.S.:
As an extra note, just in case be sure that you do not have syntax errors in the code.